# Showing module not found error i.e. 'Unable to resolve module @react-native-community/async-storage' even if the module is installed

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have installed the '@react-native-community/async-storage' module from the [official documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) and trying to run the app on the Android emulator but the app breaks down giving "module not found" error.

**This is my App.js file where I am importing the Async Storage module.**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import OnboardingScreen from '../screens/Onboarding';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export const AuthStack = () => {
  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);
  let routeName;

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then((value) => {
      if (value == null) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true'); 
        setIsFirstLaunch(true);
      } else {
        setIsFirstLaunch(false);
      }
    }); 
  
    
  
  }, []);

  if (isFirstLaunch === null) {
    return null; 
  } else if (isFirstLaunch == true) {
    routeName = 'Onboarding';
  } else {
    routeName = 'Login';
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={routeName}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Onboarding"
        component={OnboardingScreen}
        options={{header: () => null}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{header: () => null}}
      />
      
      <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**These are the dependencies in the package.json file**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.14.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
```

**This is the error**

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module @react-native-community/async-storage from C:\Users\Jayant Mukundam\Desktop\te-project\cirl_v2\App.js: @react-native-community/async-storage could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Also, I am not able to figure out how to follow those steps suggested in the error part.

Comment: Your code tries to import from `@react-native-community/async-storage`, but in your package.json you have `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`.

Comment: try replacing `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` with `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`

Comment: @ArashYounesi  Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to remove the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to wrong import statement.
try to import AsyncStorage from react-native-async-storage.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

instead of

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

in your app.js file